# Hanning Window Bandwidth

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, windowing

I am using scipy's "scipy.signal.hanning" to determine a hanning window. This method returns an array with the window and specific number of points based on your input.

More info:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.0.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.hanning.html

My question:

Is there a connection between the desirable window points output and the bandwidth of the Window?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it falls more on the theory side than programming side. As such it might be a good fit for https://dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: Yes, there is a connection.  The bandwidth of the windows is typically referred to as the noise bandwidth, which is 1.0 for a rectangular window and 1.5 for the Hann window.